# How to efficiently get all elements along 3rd direction at specified locations in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, vectorization

`A` is an `M*N*S` matrix of values and `B` is a `P*1` vector of indices of locations in an `M*N` matrix. I want to get the `P*S` matrix, `C`, that is all values along 3rd direction form `A`, at locations specified by `B` (on the `A(:, :, 1)`).
This is my current code:

```
%% sample inputs
M = 2; N = 3; S = 3;
A = reshape(1:M*N*S, M, N, S)
B = (1:3:M*N)'
P = numel(B);
%% solution
B2 = repmat(B, 1, S)+repmat((0:S-1)*M*N, P, 1);
C = A(B2)
```

But it calls `repmat` twice, and I need this in a for loop that `P` changes in every iteration. So how can I make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would *strongly discourage* the use of `O` as a variable name. It looks like a zero. Similarly, avoid a lower-case `l` as it looks like a `1`. Below I will use `S` in place of your `O`.

You can simply `reshape` your initial matrix into an `[M*N, S]` matrix and then user the indices on the first column.

```
% Collapse the first two dimensions into rows
data = reshape(A, [], size(A, 3));

% Grab the rows that correspond to the indices in B
C = data(B, :);
```

The use of `reshape` is very efficient here because MATLAB doesn't need to make a copy of the underlying data, just alter how it is accessed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my post. BTW, I think you meant `C = data(B, :);` since I used P as `numel(B)`.

Comment: @saastn Yes I did, sorry about that.